# Odoo.sh Upgrade to v15 : how to migrate obsolete but inherited views?

Tags: migration, upgrade, odoo-13

I am currently following the UPGRADE process in odoo.sh to migrate to Odoo v15.
Because some of the templates have been removed or renamed in v15, I got 100 errors similar to:

```
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: website_blog.s_latest_posts
```

Most of these errors are caused by the third party template on version 13.

How to deal with (Theme-) templates which are not existing anymore in the destination (v15) version but used as inherited template in the current version (v13)?

For example:

website_blog.s_latest_posts.xml is existing in the official src/odoo/addons in v13 but not in v15. And I have custumized this template using inherit:

```xml
<template id="my_s_latest_post" inherit_id="website_blog.s_latest_posts"><xpath="..."></xpath></template>
```

The "third party theme" module "third_party_theme" inherits from it:

```xml
<template id="thirdpartytheme_s_latest_post" inherit_id="website_blog.s_latest_posts"><xpath="..."></xpath></template>
```

and other of my custom templates which inherit from third_party_theme 's template:

```xml
<template id="my_other_s_latest_post" inherit_id="third_party_theme.thirdpartytheme_s_latest_post"><xpath="..."></xpath></template>
```

or other parts of my custom templates or third party theme CALL the original template:

```xml
<template><xpath=xxx>
<t t-call=third_party_theme.thirdpartytheme_s_latest_post...
```

And because the website_blog.s_latest_posts.xml is not existing anymore in v15, during the migration process (odoo.sh), such an error occurs: `ValueError: External ID not found in the system: website_blog.s_latest_posts`

I have heard about pre-migrate scripts to disable views during migration process:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0jQQlEnUUQ
but i can t figure out how to manage the steps to handle views (see screen shots in attach). Scripts examples (pre-migrate.py, post-migrate.py and end-migrate.py) are welcome :)

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have also tried to figure out what to do with the OpenUpgrade informations: https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade/blob/15.0/openupgrade_scripts/scripts/website_blog/15.0.1.1/upgrade_analysis.txt
For instance:

```
---Models in module 'website_blog'---
---Fields in module 'website_blog'---
---XML records in module 'website_blog'---
NEW ir.asset: website_blog.s_blog_posts_000_js
NEW ir.ui.view: website_blog.s_blog_posts
DEL ir.ui.view: website_blog.assets_editor
DEL ir.ui.view: website_blog.assets_frontend
DEL ir.ui.view: website_blog.assets_snippet_s_latest_posts_css_000
DEL ir.ui.view: website_blog.s_latest_posts
DEL ir.ui.view: website_blog.s_latest_posts_big_picture_template
NEW website.snippet.filter: website_blog.dynamic_filter_latest_blog_posts
```