# Odoo web.assets_backend.min.js - Uncaught Promise > Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, odoo

I want to trigger a click event on my custom button in Odoo treeview. But it raises an error:

```
UncaughtPromiseError > TypeError
Uncaught Promise > Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
    at Class._setDecorationClasses (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/510-ad51254/web.assets_backend.min.js:5485:169)
    at Class._renderBodyCell (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/510-ad51254/web.assets_backend.min.js:5453:39)
    at http://localhost:8069/web/assets/510-ad51254/web.assets_backend.min.js:5476:117
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Class._renderRow (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/510-ad51254/web.assets_backend.min.js:5476:80)
    at Class._renderRow (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/510-ad51254/web.assets_backend.min.js:5377:69)
    at Class._renderRow (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/417-d50faff/web.assets_common.min.js:4724:371)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Class._renderRows (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/510-ad51254/web.assets_backend.min.js:5478:119)
```

Here is my static/src/js/list_controller.js

```
odoo.define('component_creator.list_controller', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var ListController = require('web.ListController');
    var core = require('web.core');
    var _t = core._t;

    ListController.include({
        renderButtons: function () {
            var self = this;
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            if (this.modelName === 'service.master') {
                this.$buttons.find('.o_list_button_add').after(
                    $('<button>', {
                        class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm o_list_button_upload_alkeba',
                        accesskey: 'f',
                        text: _t("Import CSV JS"),
                    }).click(function () {
                        self.$('input[type=file]').click();
                    })
                );
            }
        },
    });
    core.action_registry.add('component_creator.list_controller', ListController);
    // return the object.
    return ListController;
});
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the `service.manager` tree view by defining a new [ListView](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/fr/developer/reference/frontend/javascript_cheatsheet.html#customizing-an-existing-view) and setting the [js_class](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/account/views/account_move_views.xml#L433)

Odoo uses it to add the bill upload button to the [account tree view](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/account/static/src/js/bills_upload.js#L67-L90) buttons

***Example:***

1. Extend the list view buttons template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<templates>
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons" t-name="ServiceMasterListView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="after">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary o_list_button_upload_alkeba">
                Upload
            </button>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

2. Extend the list view widget

```
odoo.define('service.master.tree', function (require) {
"use strict";
    var core = require('web.core');
    var ListController = require('web.ListController');
    var ListView = require('web.ListView');
    var viewRegistry = require('web.view_registry');

    var ServiceMasterListController = ListController.extend({
        buttons_template: 'ServiceMasterListView.buttons',
        events: _.extend({}, ListController.prototype.events, {
            'click .o_list_button_upload_alkeba': '_onUpload',
        }),

        _onUpload: function(ev) {

        }

    });

    var ServiceMasterListView = ListView.extend({
        config: _.extend({}, ListView.prototype.config, {
            Controller: ServiceMasterListController,
        }),
    });

    viewRegistry.add('service_master_tree', ServiceMasterListView);
});
```

3. Set the `js_class`

```
<record id="view_service_master_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">service.master.tree</field>
    <field name="model">service.master</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree string="Services" js_class="service_master_tree">
    </tree>
</record>
```

Comment: HiKenly, could you give an inch on this isssue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75111271/odoo-upgrade-to-v15-openupgrade-dealing-with-obsolete-but-inherited-views

Comment: Hi, Kenly, it still error :
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: QWeb2: Can't clone undefined template ListView.buttons`
` at Object.exception (web.assets_common.min.js:4451:7)`
` at Engine.add_template (web.assets_common.min.js:4467:361)`
` at web.assets_common.min.js:4939:6`

Comment: I tested the code above on Odoo 15

Comment: I use Odoo 15 too. Still error.

Comment: The error is in the `t-extend` value. Check if it has extra spaces